# Is there a way to Customize Concordion's "info box"

Tags: java, html, automated-tests, integration-testing, concordion

So when you run a concordion-test it generates a HTML which highlights the results green/red.
In this HTML page at the bottom-right corner there is this **generated** concordion info box, which shows the date, time, and how long the tests run.
My question is, can i customize it to show some custom information? (ex: The app's current version, which i'm writing the tests for. Or "foo" or anything i want personally.)
Can i customize the position of this box on the HTML?

I'm using java+html combo.[This is what the info box looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L06a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Concordion "info box" can be overridden using an extension, such as the [Timestamp Formatter Extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-timestamp-formatter-extension).

Alternatively, a simpler solution may be to leave the "info box" as-is and implement the feature separately. Use Concordion's [echo command](http://concordion.org/instrumenting/java/markdown/#echo-command) or [embed extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-embed-extension) to output arbitrary text or HTML respectively to the Concordion output.

Comment: Yes i have already used the Timestamp Formatter as you can see on the provided picture, and i couldn't find any other extension that could do the work i need. So echo it is...

Comment: Have you tried creating your own extension, based on the Timestamp Formatter code, but that adds your custom information?

Comment: Wow that's a great idea. It totally did not came to my mind. Thank you!